# jmeter:BeanShell Pre-processor is not working on unix machine

Tags: java, unix, jmeter, beanshell

i'm using a BeanShell pre-processor to read csv file before sample getting executed and to read file using opencsv-3.3.jar file (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) and the same working perfectly fine on Windows machine with both GUI and Non-GUI mode but when we execute the same on Unix machine Bean Shell processor is not retrieving any values from csv file but also not showing any error as well.

i have copied the opencsv-3.3.jar file in Jmeter Root/lib directory on both unix and windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Post your script and jmeter.log file output so we could look into the issue.

Any reason for not using JMeter's built-in components for reading CSV files? They are:

- [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function
- [CSV Data Set](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) Config Element

Comment: Yes, we need to take input from webpage itself....that is dynamic handing of input file...we need to read values from source code then prepare the csv....
Thanks for your reply...I got the solution now....actually setup was distributed and due to permission issue input.csv was not copied to one of the load generator....